# Order Topology of $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: general-topology

I read this (see picture below) a while ago and understood perfectly when I was reading connectedness, path-connectedness, least upper bound property etc, and also understood how beautiful is this. This is from **Munkres's Topology**.

[image: R^2]

My question:

> Is there any generalization of order topology for $\mathbb{R^n}$ analogous to $\mathbb{R^2}$ as described here?

If there is one can anyone tell me that?

If I do same way for $\mathbb{R^3}$, I have to write $a\times b<x\times y$, which is weird to me. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For $n=3$ you can write $(a,b,c)<(x,y,z)$ if $a<x$ or $a=x\wedge b<y$ or $a=x\wedge b=y\wedge c<z$. This can be done more generally on $\mathbb R^n$ and every order induces an order-topology.

Comment: Calling it the "dictionary order" (also known as "lexicographic order") is highly suggestive of how to generalise the order. Think about vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as words with letters being the coordinates. How would you "alphabetically" order the coordinates?

Comment: @TheoBendit yes, the visualization is also inductive. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is such topology. In $\mathbb{R}^3$, consider this order:$$(a,b,c)<(a',b',c')\iff a<a'\vee(a=a'\wedge b<b')\vee(a=a'\wedge b=b'\wedge c<c').$$ Then consider the topology generated by all intervals $\bigl((a,b,c),(a',b',c')\bigr)$ such that $(a,b,c)<(a',b',c')$.

This can be easily generalized to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thanks, the visualization is inductive (like those strips in the picture will replace into planes for $a<a',b<b'c<c'$ etc.).

Comment: @topology_001 Indeed.

Comment: just a curiosity, is there any other way to define order in $\mathbb{R^2}$?

Comment: @topology_001 Of course. For instance, since $\mathbb{R}^2$ has the same cardinal as $\mathbb R$, there is a ono-to-one function $\iota\colon\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb R$. You can define$$(x,y)<(x',y')\iff\iota(x,y)<\iota(x',y').$$

Comment: Yeah! Thanks a lot!