# Show that $T$(contains segments) is path connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Consider [dictionary order topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416402/order-topology-of-mathbbrn) in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

> Let $X$ denotes the rational points of the interval $[0,1]\times 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $T$ denotes the union of all line segments joining the point $p=0\times 1$ to points of $X$.
>
> Show that $T$ is path connected.

Well, that is easy: Note that every line segments in $T$ are connected with $p$. Hence path connected.$\tag{**}$

---

But: Consider $X=[0,1]\times 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $T$ denotes the union of all line segments joining the point $p=0\times 1$ to points of $X$.

In this case, I can use the same argument as before and **claim** that $T$ is path connected. But clearly **$T$ is not path connected** for the fact $[0,1]^2$ is not path connected.

> So, is my argument (**) is vague? Please someone help!

Comment: Why do you think the standard square is not path connected?

Comment: @M.Van It is shown in Munkres Topology that ordered square is connected but not path connected (Example 6, page 156). That is why I did not wrote that.

Comment: Ah I see, not the standard topology on the square.

Comment: Could you give the topology on each of the topological spaces you talk about?

Comment: @M.Van it is dictionary order topology. Otherwise it would be mentioned in the question.(it is mentioned that if nothing written then dictionary order topology.)

Comment: @M.Van see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416402/order-topology-of-mathbbrn) for more info

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, $T$ consists of the segments $[x, p]$, where $x\in [0,1]\times 0$. When $x\ne 0\times 0$, the open segment $(x, p)$ is a discrete subspace in the dictionary order topology, so this don’t imply path-connectedness of $T$. Also, something is wrong, because if you consider on $T$ the order topology induced from $\Bbb R^2$ then $T$ is clearly not path-connected, because if $x>0$ then $x\times [0,1]$ is a countable neighborhood of $x$ in $T$ and we can easily show that any continuous map $f$ from a unit segment $I=[0,1]$ (endowed with the standard topology) to $T$ such that $f(0)=x\times 0$ is constant. So maybe you have to consider on $T$ the order topology induced from $[0,1]^2$, maybe, even generated by a flipped order $a\times b< c\times d$ iff $b<d$ or $b=d$ and $a<c$.

Comment: From the part "Also, something is wrong,..." --- this is exactly what I am trying to say. I knew that $T$ in the second case is **not** path connected.

Comment: Actually I want to know why the argument for the first problem does not work in the next case : (i.e. why the argument when $X$ is countable does not work in the the case of when $X=[0,1]\times 0$.

Comment: It is just: I am saying "consider any two point in $T$, since they are path connected with $p$, T is path connected". Why this argument do not work in the next case!

Comment: .... So the *conclusion* is: If that argument do not work for $X=[0,1]\times 0$, how can I be sure that that argument will work for $X=$ rational points on $[0,1]\times 0$ .... I hope you understand!!!